# what is the cleanest way to remove all extra spaces from a user input comma delimited string into an array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string

A program has users typing in a comma-delimited string into an array:

```
basketball, baseball, soccer ,tennis
```

There may be spaces between the commas or maybe not.

If this string was simply `split()` on the comma, then some of the items in the array may have spaces before or after them.

What is the best way of cleaning this up?

Comment: Just interesting: the author is member on SO for a year and asked 462 question. Strange that someone has a new question every day...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use Regex.Split for this:

```
string[] tokens = Regex.Split("basketball, baseball, soccer ,tennis", @"\s*,\s*");
```

The regex `\s*,\s*` can be read as: *"match zero or more white space characters, followed by a comma followed by zero or more white space characters"*.

Answer (score 8):

```
string[] values = delimitedString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split on either comma or space, and remove the empty entries (those between a comma and a space):

```
string[] values = delimitedString.Split(new char[]{',',' '}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit:
However, as that doesn't work with values that contain spaces, instead you can split on the possible variations if your values can contain spaces:

```
string[] values = delimitedString.Split(new string[]{" , ", " ,", ", ", ","}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: As others pointed out with my answer, this will have problems with spaced values "american football, table tennis"

Comment: @SwDevMan: Yes, you are right. A added a variation that handles values containing spaces.

Comment: regarding your second solution: it won't be possible to list all possible combinations of spaces and commas (e.g. 3 spaces, one comma, 2 spaces, ...)

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "ping pong, table tennis, water polo";
string[] myArray = s.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].Trim();
```

That will preserve the spaces in the entries.

Answer (score 1):

Split the items on the comma:

```
string[] splitInput = yourInput.Split(',', StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and then use

```
foreach (string yourString in splitInput)
{
    yourString.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.Replace(" ","")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) before you split the string

Comment: OP question didnt have spaces, but you are right, this wont work for values with spaces (see David Andres answer for a better Replace)

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly split a text by ",", and then use Trim method to remove spaces on start and end of the each string. This will add support for string with spaces to your code.